# [code][/code] tags changes the posted code

Tags: wordpress, tags

I wanted to add codes to my wordpress.com hosted blog in a code friendly way. So I found this page since I can't use plugin. https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/.  First this worked as promised. But later I checked the blog's code it has been change some codes replaced with symbols like below one **&lt;servlet&gt;** I don't understand the reason for this because for a time it works as it promised. Below is how they looks in the blog site.

[image]

What I want is to show codes in a friendly way in my blog since I can't install plugins in my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the new Calypso editor on WordPress.com. There is an open GitHub issue for it [here](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso/issues/1426).

If you make sure to only edit the page in the traditional WP-Admin interface your code should not be changed.

Edit: The on-page edit link only goes to Calypso now, so to edit a post in WP-Admin, add /wp-admin to the end of your site URL and type it in your browser. Then go to Posts ->All posts (or Pages) to edit existing content.

Some older accounts still show a link to WP-Admin when you click on My Site(s), but if your account doesn't, you need to use the direct link.

Comment: you mean
**My sites -> WP-Admin -> Post** one?

Comment: Yes. I don't know of any reports of this bug happening there, but if at any time you edit the post/page in the new interface it might happen again until this bug gets fixed.

Comment: Thank you but I want to know how to get the traditional WP-Admin interface is.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I've edited my answer to add an explanation how to reach WP-Admin